# How to save compressed image in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am working in image compression using Singular value Decomposition technique.
I wrote code for it in Matlab. I compressed a image(255*255*3) of file size 8.15KB. When I save the compressed image(in jpg format) its file size exceeding the original image file size.

```
B=imread('lena.jpg');

figure,
imshow(B), title( sprintf('size=%d',numel(B)) )  // displaying the original image


A=im2double(B);

A1=A(:,:,1);

A2=A(:,:,2);

A3=A(:,:,3);

tic;


// applying svd for each layer

[U1,S1,V1]=svd(A1);

[U2,S2,V2]=svd(A2);

[U3,S3,V3]=svd(A3);

// reconstuctin compressed image


p=100;

U1p=U1(:,1:p);

V1p=V1(:,1:p);

S1p=diag(S1(1:p,1:p));

C1=U1p * diag(S1p) * V1p';

C1=255*C1;

C1=uint8(C1);

U2p=U2(:,1:p);

V2p=V2(:,1:p);

S2p=diag(S2(1:p,1:p));

C2=U2p * diag(S2p) * V2p';

C2=255*C2;

C2=uint8(C2);

U3p=U3(:,1:p);

V3p=V3(:,1:p);

S3p=diag(S3(1:p,1:p));

C3=U3p * diag(S3p) * V3p';

C3=255*C3;

C3=uint8(C3);

Q(:,:,1)=C1;

Q(:,:,2)=C2;

Q(:,:,3)=C3;


// finding size and error of the compressed image

sz = (3*(numel(U1p) + numel(V1p) + numel(S1p)));  

err = mean( abs(B(:)-Q(:)) );

toc;
t=toc;

// displying the compressed image

figure,
imshow(Q)

title( sprintf('p=%d, size=%d,err=%d', p, sz,err) );
```

please help me how to save the compressed file.

Comment: if you're reducing file size with SVDs, save only the retained singular values and the left&right eigenvectors. Don't reconstruct the image and save, which is pointless.

Comment: I think i did as u suggested only in my code.

Comment: still there is no difference. the compressed file size exceeding the original size of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Lorem Ipsum said, you are not saving a compressed image, you are saving the reconstructed image itself (Q is the reconstructed image). So you're file will be as big as an 8-bit .bmp file...

And even if you save only the relevant singular values and corresponding vectors, this should not be smaller than an .jpg format file. [Jpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) is already heavily compressed, with better techniques than SVD...

Comment: fine. but i have one more doubt.That, in the code, i used the image(225*225*3 i.e.,151875 bits) to compress and i did the compression with p=100 so i got image size 135300 bits. means i compressed the image with lesser size right?.

Comment: no, 225*225*3 is the amount of numbers you have to save. If you save it in 24-bit BMP, then that would be 225*225*3*24, in 8-bit BMP, that would be 225*225*3*8... Now you create a matrix Q that is 225*225*3 and you save it in uint8, so that's 225*225*3*8 bits of data. If you save only the singular values and corresponding vectors also in uint8 or something, you could save (100+225*100*2)*3*8(= 135300*8) and "decompress" your image as you did to calculate Q. But if you save Q that's still 225*225*3 integers you have to save.